# Change Background Color of Full Screen Application- Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, nsimageview

Good Afternoon helpful people!

I'm building a mac app that displays images. The app **will** be in fullscreen mode 100% of the time it is running.

My issue is that the images I am displaying do not fill the entire screen, therefore, showing a grayish background. Is there anyway to change this background color to Black? Or maybe it's the NSImageView that needs the background color changed?

I do not see anywhere in my Xcode Attributes Inspector to change color.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue! Any news on this / how did you get it sorted?

Comment: Yes! One moment and I will post my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is, in my case, to add an `NSBox` in storyboard and set its constraints so that it ALWAYS fills the view. Once you have done this, go to the Atrributes Inspector and change its `Fill Color` to your desired color.

The important part here is the constraints. Set Top, Bottom, Left, and Right space to 0. Hope that makes sense, i'm new to constraints.